# ESP8266 shutdown after compile

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a big problem with esp8266-1.
Im updating code (any code, even "hello wordl") to esp8266. It was working for some time (sending temp reads from dallas temp through MQTT to RPI3) and now every upload to esp8266 has effect in interruption in any wireless comunication port: mwireless mouse has big problems, wifi is jammed.
What i did wrong?

Here some simple code:

```
#define pirPin 2 // Input for HC-SR501
int pirValue;

void setup() {
   pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
   Serial.print(" Checking..."); 
   pirValue = digitalRead(pirPin);
   Serial.println(pirValue);
   delay(1000);
}
```

Conection is good, becuse i mad[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXHkk.png)e some sort of programming station for it with adapter, so i only pull it in to program.

[Arduino setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlC3t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: add a capacitor in between VCC and GND. Pullup all the GPIO pins. Check the rest pin have floating values? if so pull up the reset pin too!